# Search for instances of quoted text in batch

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Is it possible to use findstr to find "MA" <-- quotes included in search?

Tried a few things but to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just escape the quotes by adding `\` before them.`FINDSTR /C:"\"MA\"" file.txt`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be redirecting to the text file. Mind you I added redirection to your code

Comment: My bad `"^"MA^""` should be changed to `"\"MA\""`. I forgot that findstr uses \ to escape quotes.